# Preferred way of conversion to String

Tags: java, string

Which way of converting Java object to `String` would you recommend and why?
For example, assume we have:

`StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`

We can convert it to `String` in two ways. First:

```
sb.toString();
```

Second:

```
sb + "";
```

Comment: first one as second one creates extra `StringBuilder` object

Comment: @SuKu Hmm, are you sure? In my opinion the first will create only a `String` object, take a look at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#StringBuilder.toString%28%29). The second, I agree, it will create an extra `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is preferred as it is more commonly used and more efficient.

You would only use the second if the String were not empty (in which case you should append it to the StringBuilder)

The second example is more expensive because it is much the same as

```
new StringBuilder().append(sb.toString()).append("").toString();
```

Technically it does this.

```
new StringBuilder().append(String.valueOf(sb)).append("").toString();
```

the difference being that String.valueOf(null) => "null" instead of an NPE.

Comment: Can you please explain why is it more efficient? Is it linked with SuKu's comment to my question?

Comment: Wow, really ugly code. Now it's clear what is better. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference between `someObject.toString()` and `someObject + ""` is if someObject is null: the former will throw a NullPointerException whereas the latter won't (it will return "null").

If you expect your object to be non-null, then:

```
String s = someObject.toString();
```

saves an unnecessary concatenation (which might or might not be removed by the compiler).

However, if the object can be null and it is an acceptable value, I'd rather go for:

```
String.valueOf(someObject);
```

In this example, if `someObject` is null, it will return "null" and won't throw an exception.

Comment: I prefer getting an exception signalling the problem early, and allow me to fix the bug, as having null instead of the actual wanted result.

Comment: @JBNizet completely agreed. Rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

The first is more commonly used for String Builder as @Peter Lawrey mentioned.  However when *casting* to a String, it can be better to do...

```
(String) myVariable;
```

rather than...

```
myVariable.toString();
```

The reason for this is it's possible the second may throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third possibility:

```
    Objects.toString(Object o, String nullDefault)
```

the second argument is returned if the first is `null`,
otherwise `o.toString()` is returned.

(There is also `Objects.toString(Object o)`, which returns the same as `String.valueOf`)